# Angularjs + grunt + bower + Gitlab CI. Setup for testing

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, gitlab-ci

I've a GitLab CI runner that runs every time I push code in my branch. 
The problem is: I use npm+bower to have all dependencies I need, but I don't want to download all dependencies for each test: it's a waste of network and time.

So I came up with this script. Does it make any sense?

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
npm config set prefix ~/npm
export PATH="~/npm/bin:$PATH"
source ~/.bash_profile
npm install
rm -f ~/bower/bower.json
cp bower.json ~/bower
pushd ~/bower
bower update
bower install
popd
mkdir bower_components
cp -r ~/bower/bower_components bower_components
grunt test
```

Anyway, a problem I'm facing is it always goes on timeout with bower:

```
bower angular-cookies#1.2.16                  ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Also, it didn't finish once, so I'm not sure, but it seems it re-download all packages every time.

I tried to search on the net, but I didn't find anything. There is a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve? (Also with a completely different strategy. I also have ssh access to the runner)

Comment: Hey, I am trying to do the same thing and I'm also using bower, npm and grunt. But for me "npm install" doesn't even run through. It cancels after 30 minutes, telling me the execution of the command took too long. Does "npm install" work for you without breaking up?

Comment: @error1337 yes, it works. At the end I adapted the script I just posted as reply, hope this could help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE 2016**

GitLab runners now use *.gitlab-ci.yml* that has support for cache.

This is our script now:

```
image: *****/frontend

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

before_script:
  - npm prune
  - npm install
  - bower prune --allow-root
  - bower install --allow-root

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - bower_components/
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REPO"

sample_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - grunt build
    - grunt test
    - grunt jscs --force
    - grunt jshint --force

sample_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
    - development
  script:
    - grunt build babel uglify:dist
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
```

Now, the interesting thing is `key: "$CI_BUILD_REPO"` in the cache section - this set the cache to be the same for all the build in the repo. This is why we use `npm prune` and `bower prune` - to be sure only modules we really need are in the build at the end

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

So, at the end I use this script:

```
rm -f ~/bower/bower.json
rm -f ~/bower/package.json
cp bower.json ~/bower
cp package.json ~/bower
pushd ~/bower
npm install
bower install
popd
cp -r ~/bower/bower_components .
cp -r ~/bower/node_modules .
grunt build
grunt test
```

Also, to avoid timeout from github I use https instead of git to download code, with the command

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Comment: can you share the full script (`scipt.sh` & `.gitlab-ci.yml`) ? its a .sh one, right? Also I'm curious how you've setup the runner (what commands you've used.

Comment: hi @el.severo, this is an old config for an old version of gitlab, when there wasn't yet the `.gitlab-ci.yml` - we haven't converted yet that server to the new version

Comment: @el.severo I updated the answer with our .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer

Comment: I got this error: npm: command not found. Do I need to specify each time to download npm?

Comment: A predfined value `CI_BUILD_REPO` is deprecated since version `9.0`. Use `CI_REPOSITORY_URL` instead. See also [**GitLab Docs**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/deprecated_variables.html#gitlab-90-renamed-variables).